# Error: CS0106, ayuda

Tags: c#

Tengo este error hace días en mi windows forms de visual studio y ya no sé que hacer, si alguien sabe algo o le ha pasado por favor digame como resolverlo. Desde, ya gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tendras que mostrar el codigo completo. Seguro que tienes el metodo dentro de una clase?

Comment: Si lo tengo....

Answer (score 0):

¿Este método está dentro del form?

Si esto es así, el error es debido a que el metodo estático dentro del form debería ser private, no public.

Si requieres acceder a esta función desde otra clase u otro form, crea una clase estática y ahí si puedes utilizar el modificador public para que otros elementos, forms o clases puedan acceder.

Comment: Amigo ahí intenté y me marco que no podía declarar medios de instancia en una clase estática.

Comment: Una clase estática NO se instancia.
Supongo que lo que estas haciendo, porque no estás posteando código, es crear public static class ClaseEstatica()
y luego estás haciendo ClaseEstatica miClase = nes ClaseEstatica, eso es un error, una clase estática no se instancia, si tu objetivo era hacer miClase.FuncionEstatica() eso está mal, debe ser ClaseEstatica.FuncionEstatica()

Comment: no la instancie, me marca eso en la función.

Comment: Sinceramente, no entiendo que pasó, de un día para el otro me marcó estos errores sin que yo modificara nada.